# What's the strength of adding to Z, that the well founded world is the cumulative hierarchy?

Tags: set-theory

The principle $\sf WF=H $, is the assertion that "every well-founded set is an element of some stage of the cumulative hierarchy, and vise verse".

We define well-founded as:

$\sf WF(x) \iff \neg \exists y: dmc(y) \land x \in y$

Where:

$dmc(y) \iff \forall a \in y \, \exists b \in y: b \in a$

Now we define $V_\alpha$ recursively along the usual manner as:

$$ V_\beta = \bigcup \{ \mathcal P (V_\alpha): \alpha < \beta \}$$

Axiom: $\sf \forall x: WF(x) \iff \exists \alpha: x \in V_\alpha$

It is this axiom that I call as $\sf WF=H$, i.e. the well founded world is itself the cumulative hierarchy.

Now I don't think that $\sf Z$ can prove that result. So my question is:

> What's the strength of $\sf Z + WF=H$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\small\sf  +=$ is equiconsistent with $ \small \sf Z+``\forall x \exists \alpha \, (x \in V_\alpha)"$.

Every axiom of $\small \sf Z+``\forall x \exists \alpha \, (x \in V_\alpha)"$ holds in $\small \sf +=$ when relativized to $\small \sf F$.